# Reading a double from a text file in java

Tags: java, load, double

Can someone please explain to me why I get the error 'InputMismatchException' on the the line where I try to read in a double? Thanks!

```
        int num=inFile.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
            String inName=inFile.next();
            double inPrice=inFile.nextDouble();           // <<<this line
            Book bookInFile = new Book(inName, inPrice);
            books.add(bookInFile);
        }
```

Data in the text file:

```
4
War and Peace
12.99
Green Eggs and Ham
3.99
Harry Potter
5.99
james
5.0
```

Comment: Well what data is in the file? It's impossible for us to know why you're getting the error without knowing the data...

Comment: Ah sorry, data in the file is:                                      4
War and Peace
12.99
Green Eggs and Ham
3.99
Harry Potter
5.99
james
5.0

Answer (score 1):

try this approach it will Solves your problem .

```
double d ;
        BufferedReader reader;
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourTextFile.txt"));
            String line= reader.readLine();       
            while(line !=null){
                try{
                    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line)+" is an Integer.");
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                try{
                    d=Double.valueOf(line);
                    System.out.println(d+" is a double.");

                }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    System.out.println("Not Double ' "+line+" '");
                }
                }
                line=reader.readLine();
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To know why you are getting this exception, you can do some R & D.Like,
use next() instead of nextDouble() and see what you get.
If compiler asks for double then use nextDouble. One more thing, this exception occurs when recieved token is not matching the pattern.For example, it must be getting non double token after it is getting double, may be  it is getting next line or carriage return

Comment: When I change it from nextDouble(); to next(); the compiler says:                                                        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to double

Comment: ok. In your file after every doube value there is token for new line. Get that token with next(). See if your problem gets resolved.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by token?

Comment: I just added inFile.next(); after the, nextDouble(); line, still getting these errors: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)

Comment: In answer to the question about tokens, generally a token is an opaque block that can be passed around by functions without one of the parties knowing what's in it (eg. get a token from a server, then pass the token back to do something.), but specifically, it is the unit of data read in a single function call, kind of like a "word" if you were reading to the next space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Scanner will by default use `whitespace` as the delimeter, so what you're actually getting back is:

```
War
and
Peace
12.99
Green
Eggs
and
Ham
```

and when the `nextDouble` line is reached it obviously can't convert `and` to a double.

Change the delimiter to be a newline and your code should work:

```
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
     sc.useDelimiter("\n");
```

Comment: how exactly do I implement this code into mine? Do i say usrIn.useDelimiter("\n"); before i read for the String and double? UsrIn is the name of my Scanner btw.

Comment: just add usrIn.userDelimter("\n"); immediately after the line you declare the Scanner (provided its been created of course).  I assume you're using a Scanner? In other words, what type of class is inFile?

Comment: this is what my load method looks like now, still not working :S:      public void readFile(String fileName){
     try{
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
      int num=inFile.nextInt();
      inFile.useDelimiter("\n");
      for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
       String inName=inFile.nextLine();
       double inPrice=inFile.nextDouble();
       Book bookInFile = new Book(inName, inPrice);
       books.add(bookInFile);
      }
      inFile.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("File not found.");
     }

Comment: Try this:             Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
            inFile.useDelimiter("\n");
            int num = inFile.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                String inName = inFile.next();
                double inPrice = inFile.nextDouble();